# 2D GameEngine Gameloop - Render Interpolation/Partial Ticks

Tags: java, 2d, interpolation, lwjgl, game-loop

Im trying to code a gameloop for my own 2d game engine. My problem is that i need the correct delta time or a value for the frame interpolation (a value between 0 and 1 - how far the next update is) because my game runs at 30 updates and "infinte" (no cap) fps.

I tried many gameloops but nothing has the frame interpolation.
I need this value because i update with 30 updates so its very laggy when i render it.

```java
    public void gameLoop(GameContainer container, ApplicationConfiguration config, SettingsConfiguration settingsConfig) {
        this.initDisplay(container, config, settingsConfig);
        this.init();
        this.printInfos();

        window.initGL();

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        float delta = 0.0F;
        double ns = 1000000000.0D / this.UPDATE_CAP;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;

        while(this.running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            if(delta >= 1.0F) {
                this.input(delta);
                this.update(delta);
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }

            this.render(delta);
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;

                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " | Updates: " + updates);
                debugFPS = frames;
                debugUpdates = updates;

                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }

            if(window.shouldClose()) {
                this.shutdown();
            }
        }

        window.destroy();
    }
```

The Method initDisplay initialize the window with GLFW.
Then i initialize the assets and after that i print some informations about the game.

window.initGL(); call the GL11 methods like projection and clearColor

Comment: this.UPDATE_CAP is 30.0D (30 Updates per second)